# Problema com @FacesConverter

Tags: jsf, wildfly

Bom dia a todos.

Não sei o que fazer para resolver este problema no `@FacesConverter(forClass=Fabricante.class)` que implementei...

O metodo `getAsString` é chamado com valores nulos.

Todos os parametros (`FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value`) chegam com null.

O teste que estou realizando é na chamada para a edição de registros a partir da lista de pesquisa conforme o print anexo.

Quando clico em Editar o facesConverter é chamado porém os valores estão nullos, conforme prints.

Isso só funciona no TOMCAT?

Estou tentando rodar esta implementação no WILDFLY 8 e não está funcionando.

Não sei o que fazer... alguém poderia me orientar ?

desde já agradeço a todos.

Obrigado.

XHTML:

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Novo fabricante TESTE</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">

    <f:metadata>
        <o:viewParam name="fabricante" value="#{cadastroFabricanteBean.fabricante}" converters="fabricanteConverter" />
    </f:metadata>

    <h:outputText value="#{cadastroFabricanteBean.fabricante}"/>
    <br />
    <h:outputText value="fabricante"/>

    <h:form id="frmCadastro">
        <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar" action="#{cadastroFabricanteBean.salvar}" update="frmCadastro"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Outro Salvar" id="botaoSalvar1" action="#{cadastroFabricanteBean.salvar}" update="frmCadastro"/>
            </p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                <p:button value="Pesquisa" outcome="/fabricante/PesquisaFabricantes.xhtml"/>
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px"
                columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
            <p:outputLabel value="Código" for="codigo"/>
            <p:inputText id="codigo" size="20" maxlength="20" value="#{cadastroFabricanteBean.fabricante.codigo}" readonly="true"/>

            <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
            <p:inputText id="nome" size="60" maxlength="80" value="#{cadastroFabricanteBean.fabricante.nome}"/>
        </p:panelGrid>

        <h:dataTable value="#{cadastroFabricanteBean.fabricantes}" var="fabricante" border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{fabricante.codigo}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{fabricante.nome}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>



    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Pesquisa de Fabricantes</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
    <h1>Pesquisa de Fabricantes</h1>

    <h:form id="frmPesquisa">
        <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:commandButton value="Novo" id="botaoNovo" action="/fabricante/CadastroFabricante.xhtml"/>
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>

        <p:dataTable id="fabricantesTable" value="#{pesquisaFabricanteBean.fabricantes}" var="fabricante"
                style="margin-top: 20px" emptyMessage="Nenhum fabricante encontrado." rows="20"
                paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" paginatorPosition="bottom">
                <p:column headerText="Código" style="text-align: center; width: 100px">
                    <h:outputText value="#{fabricante.codigo}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Nome">
                    <h:outputText value="#{fabricante.nome}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 100px; text-align: center">
                    <p:button outcome="CadastroFabricante" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar">
                        <f:param name="fabricante" value="#{fabricante.codigo}"/>
                    </p:button>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" oncomplete="PF('confirmacaoExclusao').show()"
                            process="@this" update=":frmPesquisa:confirmacaoExclusaoDialog">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{pesquisaFabricanteBean.fabricanteSelecionado}" value="#{fabricante}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmacaoExclusaoDialog" widgetVar="confirmacaoExclusao"
                message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir o fabricante #{pesquisaFabricanteBean.fabricanteSelecionado.nome}?"  
                header="Exclusão de fabricante" severity="alert">
            <p:button value="Não" onclick="confirmacaoExclusao.hide(); return false;" />
            <p:commandButton value="Sim" update=":frmPesquisa:fabricantesTable"
                    onclick="confirmacaoExclusao.hide()" action="#{pesquisaFabricanteBean.excluir}" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

```
package com.jobstream.jboss.controller;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import com.jobstream.jboss.modelo.Fabricante;

@FacesConverter(forClass=Fabricante.class)
public class FabricanteConverter implements Converter {


    public FabricanteConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        System.out.println("FabricanteConverter :: getAsObject :: " + value);
        Fabricante retorno = null;
        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        Fabricante f = (Fabricante) value;
        if (f.getCodigo() == null) {
            System.out.println("?????");
        }
        if (value != null) {
            Long codigo = ((Fabricante) value).getCodigo();
            System.out.println("FabricanteConverter :: getAsString :: " + codigo);
            String retorno = (codigo == null ? null : codigo.toString());

            return retorno;
        }

        return "";
    }

}
```

[image: Print do debug]

Comment: O converter é pra qual campo no xhtml ?

Comment: O converter é para o botão de edição:

<p:button outcome="CadastroFabricante" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Editar">
          <f:param name="fabricante" value="#{fabricante.codigo}"/>
</p:button>